# PHP: get query result from the database and encode it to JSON array and pass to Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm currently working with a PHP code that queries a series of characters and find out the matching result from the database. After getting the result, I convert it into an array.

So, the function is as follows.

```
public function findFriends($name) {
    $connection = $this->db->connect();
    $query = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE lower(users.`name`) LIKE '%$name%'";

    $return_arr = array();
    $fetch = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {
        $return_arr[] = $row['name'];   
    }

    return $return_arr;
}
```

with the returned value above, I now encode it into the JSON array.

```
$user = $db->findFriends($name);

if ($user != false) {

    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];

    echo json_encode($response);

}
```

And now, I get the JSON data in Android.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray arr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("user");

for(int i=0; i<arr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonData = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    String item = jsonData.getString("name");
}
```

But here seems to be a problem. When I run the code in the Android application and start query, I get a message like this.

```
JSONException caught: Value user of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray.
```

Comment: $response["user"] is an associated array (it has element with `name` key). Does `JSONArray` represents an json array (`[e1, e2, e3]`) or object (`{'k1': e1, 'k2': e2, 'k3': e3}`) ?

Answer (score 0):

In your php when you loop through your db results try this.

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {
    $return_arr[] = array("name"=>$row['name']);   
}

    $new_array[] = array("user"=>$return_arr);
    return $new_array;
```

then json_encode that returned array;

Answer (score 0):

You messed with json structure:

```
$user = $db->findFriends($name);
// here you'll get ($user = ["name1", "name2", "name3"])

if ($user != false) {

    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];

    // and here 'll be ({"error": false, "user": {"name": ["name1", "name2", "name3"]}})
    echo json_encode($response);

}
```

So, when you call

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
```

You'll get:

```
jsonObject = {"error": false, "user": {"name": ["name1", "name2", "name3"]}}
```

Where `jsonObject["user"]` is an key-value object, not array.

**To do it right if you intend to transfer not only `name`s in future:**

```
public function findFriends($name) {
    $connection = $this->db->connect();
    // safely can extend to something like `SELECT id, name FROM ...`, it won't break json consistency/structure
    $query = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE lower(users.`name`) LIKE '%$name%'";

    $return_arr = array();
    $fetch = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {
        $return_arr[] = $row; // not "$row['name']"
    }

    return $return_arr;
}

$users = $db->findFriends($name);

if ($user != false) {

    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["user"] = $users; // not "$response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"]"

    echo json_encode($response);

}
```

*Note: ...cause it's wierd: you asking PHP server-side "Is there friends with name 'Alec'?" and it answers you "Of course, silly, here it is: {"error": false, "users": [{"name": "Alec Vasovski"}]}". Doesn't you intend to do something with received data futurehand? Like, give the app user the link to that friend with smth. like `handleFriendUserClick(int userId)`, and you need to transfer that `userId` in json also? Uh, nevermind, I'm going off-topic...*

Comment: So you assume that the problem is on the Android side, not on the PHP, right?

Comment: Added code to fix code on PHP side. Returned json now will be `{"error": false, "user": [{"name": "name1"}, {"name": "name2"}, {"name": "name3"}]}` and will be OK with existing android-side code

Comment: ... however, if you do intend to transfer only `name` fields via that json-request and will never extend it in future, then it can be simplified to return just array of names.

Answer (score 0):

Try to dump out the JSON you created using `json_encode`. I think you will learn a lot and figured out how your array is being converted into a JSON object.

Comment: Once you have done that. You can update your array structure to get the desired JSON data arrangement.